# jquery checkbox to set input type

Tags: jquery

I have a html page which requires two passwords, if these do not match a div appears to say so. Within the div a checkbox is also shown when the user checks this it should change the password type to text and vice versa. I seem to be having problems detecting if the checkbox is detected or not.

```
$("#password_error").html('Passwords do not match <br /> <span class="password_error"><input type="checkbox" id="password_text" /> Show Characters</span>');
  $("#password_error").show("slow");
  checkbox_status();

function checkbox_status()
{
 if ($('#password_text').is(':checked'))
 {
  $('input:password[type="text"]');
 }
}
```

The ID on the input box for password is "password".

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Be aware that IE has issues with this behaviour (changing from `type="password"` to `type="text"` isn't allowed, and can't be set via JS): http://www.alistapart.com/articles/the-problem-with-passwords/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#check').attr('checked');
```

It will show true or false.

### Example

As Dave pointed out, changing the type isn't a good idea, a better idea is to have two inputs, one text and one password. Start with the password showing and the text hidden, that way if javascript is disabled it degrades peacefully. You can then toggle each and update the value on check. Here's a working example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#check').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $('#plaintext').show().val($('#password').val());
            $('#password').hide();
        } else {
            $('#password').show().val($('#plaintext').val());
            $('#plaintext').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P8tg5/

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post two links apparently... odd. Anyways, I just took the first example off and added the functional example.

Comment: Looks good, I will try it thanks :) Your rep will build fast if all your answers are like this haha.

Answer (score 0):

**working Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/sB9NJ/

**html**

```
   password: <input type='password' id='password1'><br>
    retype password: <input type='password' id='password2'><br>
    <div id='messageHolder' style="display:none">
    show passwords<input type='checkbox' id='togglePassword' />
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
      jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#password2').bind('blur',_checkPasswords);
    jQuery('#togglePassword').bind('change',_togglePasswordText);
});

    function _checkPasswords()
    {
        if(jQuery('#password1').val()!=jQuery('#password2').val())
        {
             jQuery('#messageHolder').show();
        }
    }

function _togglePasswordText()
{
  if(jQuery('#togglePassword').is(':checked'))
    {       
        jQuery('#password2,#password1').each(function(){
            var _elm= jQuery(this);
            var _val=_elm.val();
            var _id= _elm.attr('id')
            jQuery(this).replaceWith('<input id='+_id+' value='+_val+' type="text">')
        });
     }
   else
   {
        jQuery('#password2,#password1').each(function(){
            var _elm= jQuery(this);
            var _val=_elm.val();
            var _id= _elm.attr('id')
            jQuery(this).replaceWith('<input id='+_id+' value='+_val+' type="password">')
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the error in firebug:  uncaught exception: type property can't be changed

Comment: @Elliott: the same error is reported in Web Inspector for Chrome (Ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: actually browsers dont allow password type to be changed to text: that's why it was throwing error . just fixed it. check the demo. check box will appear only after  there is a mismatch found in both passwords

Comment: Could you explain the "bind" event if possible? Thanks